# how to split all values even the empty ones in Java

Tags: java, split

I have this List named "lines":

```
[|||dezd||, |a|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||, |||||dezdezd||||, |||||||||||||dezdzedze|||dezdzede|||dzedzedzed|]
```

I implemented this:

```
for (String line1 : lines) {
    String[] array = null;
    array = line1.split("\\|");

    for(int i = 0 ;i<array.length;i++){
        listOfData.add(array[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println(listOfData);
```

The result is like this ,the problem is that some empty values between "|" didn't added to my list:

```
[, , , dezd, , a, , , , , , dezdezd, , , , , , , , , , , , , , dezdzedze, , , dezdzede, , , dzedzedzed]
```

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Some empty values between "|" didn't appear in the final List

Comment: @yasser101991 indeed, I made a mistake while running your code, now I also have the issue...

Comment: Printing the entire array I got this: `[[, , , dezd, , , , a, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , dezdezd, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , dezdzedze, , , dezdzede, , , dzedzedzed, ]]` is this what you are after? (There is an extra value at the end for sure.

Comment: @npinti , this was aslo my initial output, put the input is a list, not a String...

Comment: I think I understand what is happening. Would it be possible to provide us with a sample of what you are expecting?

Comment: @npinti I'm expecting the same result you got but as a list in the input (that i named "lines").

Comment: @npinti ,TomJonckheere ,I solved my problem , you can read my answer. Thank you fo helping me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could resolve it:

```
for (String line1 : lines) {
String[] array = null;
array = line1.split("\\|",-1);

for(int i = 1 ;i<array.length-1;i++){
listOfData.add(array[i]);
}}

System.out.println(listOfData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.split()` with a negative second argument, you will get all the "empty" elements in the result array as well:

```
line1 = "|a||b||";
array = line1.split( "\\|"  , -1 );
assertThat( array.length , equalTo( 6 ) ); // { "", "a", "", "b", "", "" }
```

Is that what you expect?

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you , that's mostly what i expect even it add 2 extra values in the begin and in the end , i'm trying to remove them.